# Why does my flag keep getting set to false?

Tags: java, validation, do-while

Hello I am writing a simple program for a user to take a 3 question test. I am trying to validate the user input however if the user enters in a loop to enter the correct data because they previously entered the wrong data they cannot get out of the loop. Even if there next answer is correct. Something is setting one of my flags to false and I cannot figure out what. I tried debugging it to no avail.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ALittleQuiz {
private static int correct = 0;
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Are you read for the quiz? ");
    keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("Okay, here it comes!");
    questionOne();
    questionTwo();
    questionThree();

    System.out.println("Overall, you got "+correct+" out of 3 correct.");
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
}

public static void questionOne(){

    System.out.println("Q1) What is the capital of Alaska?");
    System.out.println("    1) Melbourne");
    System.out.println("    2) Anchorage");
    System.out.println("    3) Juneau");
    System.out.print("> ");
    getUserInputForQuestionOne();
}

public static void questionTwo(){

    System.out.println("Q2) Can you store the value 'cat' in a variable of type int? ");
    System.out.println("    1) Yes");
    System.out.println("    2) No");
    System.out.print("> ");
    getUserInputForQuestionTwo();
}

public static void questionThree(){

    System.out.println("Q3) What is the result of  9+6/3?");
    System.out.println("    1) 5");
    System.out.println("    2) 11");
    System.out.println("    3) 15/3");
    System.out.print("> ");
    getUserInputForQuestionThree();
}

public static void getUserInputForQuestionOne(){
    int testvar = 0;

        try{
            Scanner inputForQuestionOne = new Scanner(System.in);
            testvar = inputForQuestionOne.nextInt();
            validateUserInputForQuestionOne(testvar);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: invalid entry please try again");
            getUserInputForQuestionOne();
        }
}

public static void getUserInputForQuestionTwo(){
    int testvar = 0;

    try{
        Scanner inputForQuestionTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
        testvar = inputForQuestionTwo.nextInt();
        validateUserInputForQuestionTwo(testvar);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: invalid entry please try again");
        getUserInputForQuestionTwo();
    }
}

public static void getUserInputForQuestionThree(){
    int testvar = 0;

    try{
        Scanner inputForQuestionThree = new Scanner(System.in);
        testvar = inputForQuestionThree.nextInt();
        validateUserInputForQuestionThree(testvar);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: invalid entry please try again");
        getUserInputForQuestionThree();
    }
}

public static void validateUserInputForQuestionOne(int choiceOne){

        if(choiceOne >= 1 && choiceOne <= 3){
            sendResponseForQuestionOneToDetermineIfCorrectOrNot(choiceOne);

        }else {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2 or 3 for your selection");
            getUserInputForQuestionOne();
        }
}

public static void validateUserInputForQuestionTwo(int choiceTwo){

    if(choiceTwo >= 1 && choiceTwo <= 3){
        sendResponseForQuestionTwoToDetermineIfCorrectOrNot(choiceTwo);

    }else {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2 for your selection");
        getUserInputForQuestionTwo();
    }
}

public static void validateUserInputForQuestionThree(int choiceThree){

    if(choiceThree >= 1 && choiceThree <= 3){
        sendResponseForQuestionThreeToDetermineIfCorrectOrNot(choiceThree);

    }else {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2 or 3 for your selection");
        getUserInputForQuestionThree();
    }
}

public static void sendResponseForQuestionOneToDetermineIfCorrectOrNot(int validChoiceOne){

    switch (validChoiceOne){
        case 1: System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct\n");
            break;
        case 2: System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct\n");
            break;
        case 3: System.out.println("That's right\n");
            correct++;
            break;
    }
}

public static void sendResponseForQuestionTwoToDetermineIfCorrectOrNot(int validChoiceTwo){

    switch (validChoiceTwo){
        case 1: System.out.println("Sorry, 'cat' is a string. Ints can only store numbers\n");
            break;
        case 2: System.out.println("That's right\n");
            correct++;
            break;
    }
}

public static void sendResponseForQuestionThreeToDetermineIfCorrectOrNot(int validChoiceThree){

    switch (validChoiceThree){
        case 1: System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct\n");
            break;
        case 2: System.out.println("That's right\n");
            correct++;
            break;
        case 3: System.out.println("Sorry, that is not correct\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Here is what is happening in my terminal:

```
Are you ready for a quiz? y
Okay, here it comes!

Q1) What is the capital of Alaska?
    1) Melbourne
    2) Anchorage
    3) Juneau
> 456
Please enter 1, 2 or 3 for your selection
Q1) What is the capital of Alaska?
    1) Melbourne
    2) Anchorage
    3) Juneau
> 3
That's right

Please enter 1, 2 or 3 for your selection
Q1) What is the capital of Alaska?
    1) Melbourne
    2) Anchorage
    3) Juneau
> 2
Sorry, that is not correct

Please enter 1, 2 or 3 for your selection
Q1) What is the capital of Alaska?
    1) Melbourne
    2) Anchorage
    3) Juneau
>
```

Edit: So after reading the article one of you had posted I went back to the drawing board and was able to resolve my issue. I do want to thank those that took the time to help me with this. I updated my code which I believe is a lot more comprehensible and easier to look at. Above is my newly created code. If anyone has any notes on this I would much appreciate it!

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: Well I ran it through the debugger and the flag in "validateQuestionOneUserInput" keeps getting set to false. I am not sure why though. I ran it and for some reason it is storing the wrong value and it doesn't get overwritten? I am not too sure.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of questionOne, you make a call to validateQuestionOneUerInput. In validateQuestionOneUerInput, if the user enters something other than 1, 2, or 3, it sets flagForQuestionOne and then calls questionOne again. Regardless of the result of this call, flagForQuestionOne is false, so you now have an infinite loop.

That method could see if the user's response is valid or not and return true or false, or could throw an exception for invalid input, but should not re-call questionOne.

Answer (score 0):

in the do while loop, instead of using the flag, you are checking the flag equals == false.

Below is incorrect because when you set the `flag` value to `true` the while condition evaluates to false.

```
while (flag == false);
```

Change it to

```
while(flag)
```